# Storing objects in Meteor sessions

Tags: javascript, dictionary, meteor, session-state

I need to store an object (dictionary) in Meteor session (for example: search criteria), but it is not clear for me what is the best way to do it.

Using `Session.set` and `Session.get` works, but is cumbersome, as it appears to copy the whole object:

```
var dict = Session.get("x");
dict['some key'] = 5;
Session.set("x", dict)
```

Using global variable does not require copying objects, but does not fire reactivity (e.g. for global variable `dict` putting `dict['some key'] = 5;` does not fire templates dependent on `dict`).

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add reactivity to other objects using the Deps package if you need to customise things in a way that's more appropriate for dealing with dictionaries or whatever other structure - have a look at [this video](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDoQFjAB&url=https://www.eventedmind.com/feed/vhdWPskmLjNDoqjYd&ei=YO_BUvDfAeTt0gXg_4GgDg&usg=AFQjCNHTxEyLdDnHXFR4HNptMxl7PWwgyQ&sig2=L7qjl2gWRiB1cwwjusQE4g&bvm=bv.58187178,d.d2k).  Clearly, the syntax is always going to be minimally more cumbersome than for vanilla variables, but it's perfectly possible to make things pretty concise this way.